# How to create TBase class instance

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, thrift

I'm trying to deserialize Thrift objects from byte array.

In all examples I've found, the deserializer modifies an instance of `org.apache.thrift.TBase` interface given to it.
**How can I create an instance of `TBase`?**

```
TDeserializer deserializer = new TDeserializer(new TCompactProtocol.Factory());
byte[] data = ...// my serialized thrift object
TBase instance = ... // where to get this one ???

deserializer.deserialize((TBase) instance, data);
```

Code of the `deserialize` method:

```
public void deserialize(TBase base, byte[] bytes) throws TException {
    deserialize(base, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

Instead, you create an instance of the (outermost) object you want to deserialize.

Due to the way Thrift works, in RPC scenarios that information is usually implicitly known and therefore not serialized. IOW, for serialization purposes, you have to know what type that is by means of your own code.

Since that can easily become a nightmare if multiple types of "data records" are involved, an approach like to following has proven very handy (and extensible):

```
union Outer {
  1:  MyCoolClass cool;
  2:  SomeOtherData  other;
  3:  Foobar  foobar;
  // can be extended with other types as needed
}
```

Using that construct for serialization and deserialization, you know that the instance to be read/written is always an `Outer`.